# Getting AssertionError when trying to connect to Microsoft SQL server with Java

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect an Android application to a database hosted on azure but get the following error whenever I run my code:

```
    Process: com.traders.scanner, PID: 27389
    java.lang.AssertionError: numMsgsRcvd:1 should be less than numMsgsSent:1
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:4830)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.nextPacket(IOBuffer.java:4791)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.ensurePayload(IOBuffer.java:4767)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readBytes(IOBuffer.java:5060)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:712)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:700)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:895)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:883)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:936)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:900)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:722)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:238)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:217)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1323)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:236)
        at com.traders.scanner.model.Singleton.lambda$openConnection$0(Singleton.java:63)
        at com.traders.scanner.model.-$$Lambda$Singleton$T1DpXa4dlvxveN6-oATiN8Z-WrI.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

this is the code I use to connect with

````
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("*** Unable to register driver");
        }
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);) {
            System.out.println("Connection successful");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("*** SQL exception " + e.getMessage());
        }```
````

Comment: Can you mark below response as an answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

**It seems like there is an open issue/bug on this: [#964](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/issues/964)**

*Looks like you're not the only person to encounter this. I would recommend you to follow up on the same issue with the PG.*

Let me know if this answer helps.